# How do I switch the email name syntax in an on-premises enviroment while preserving emailname compatiblity?

Tags: email, user-accounts, exchange

I want to switch from an email/name syntax like:

JDenver@domain.de 
to 
John.Denver@domain.com

I also need to make sure that people are able to reach them with their old email adress/name.

Is there some kind of build policy based on the domain controller?

Up-to-date Windows server versions here. We are unfortunately using romain profiles. Owa is used as well (Exchange 365).

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 365, did you mean Office 365/Exchange Online?
For cloud-only Office 365 organizations, bulk email address changes can be made when adding a new domain to your tenant, or at any time you can bulk add SMTP addresses to multiple mailboxes using PowerShell.

Comment: No. And no we want to stay with our current domain.